# Query by UNIX TIMESTAMP not working in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have this query:

```
select * from applications 
where created_at between FROM_UNIXTIME(1270080000) and FROM_UNIXTIME(1554076800)
```

Which works and returns results as expected. But fails when running tests using sqlite.

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such function: FROM_UNIXTIME

Is there a different query I can use that will also pass tests?

Comment: What part of the error message do you not understand?  You are using a MySQL function.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I was just after a solution that covered both mysql and sqlite. Couldn't find one.

Comment: @mikelovelyuk in that case use proper date types. Pass values as strongly-typed date parameters. Use ISO8601 wherever you can't use date parameters. All databases understand dates. A Unix timestamp is just an integer that needs translation before it can be used.

Comment: @mikelovelyuk if you check the [Date and Time DataType](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) section in `Datatypes in SQLite` you'll see that you can use an `integer` as the storage type of your field and store the timestamp (in *seconds*) there directly. The problem with that is that the query won't be portable to other databases.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: SQLite does not have a "proper" DATE or TIMESTAMP type. It stores everything as a string - even if you declare it as a `date`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name according to the docs `the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER values` and `Applications can chose to store dates and times in any of these formats`.

Comment: What format are you storing dates in your `created_at` column? If they're also unix times, it's trivial. Otherwise you have to use `strftime()` to convert it to a unix timestamp, or convert the timestamps you're comparing against to the same format as the column. (And possibly do some casting so you don't end up trying to compare a string holding an integer to an integer, depending on your column affinities and what values you convert).

Answer (score 0):

try like below

```
select * from applications where created_at between
 DATETIME(ROUND(1270080000 / 1000), 'unixepoch') and DATETIME(ROUND(1554076800 / 1000), 'unixepoch')
```

[documentation](https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Comment: Why are you dividing by 1000?

Comment: @Shawn because some Unix Epoch is given in milliseconds, although the standard is seconds.